# Adding custom functions to lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've added lodash to my project as it adds some great functions. However, I would like to add a utility function. Is there a way I can add my function to the '`_.`' syntax? In other words, I'd love to be able to call '`_.myFunction(someParam);`'

Is there a way to extend lodash in JavaScript? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `_.mixin` function to add your custom function:

```
_.mixin({
  'myFunction' : function(someParam) {
    //body of function
  }
});
```

[**Lodash mixin**](http://lodash.com/docs#mixin)

Comment: If I `require('lodash')` in one file and create this mixin, will it be available other places I `require()` it?

Comment: and then how will that function be used? you didn't say

Comment: that function is then use as `_.myFunction` (or whatever you named the mixin)